# Why does my compiler causes an error due compiling my .ts file into .js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, tsconfig, module.exports

I have 2 .ts files:

linked_list.ts

```
class Node {
  *****
}
class LinkedList{
  *****
}
export {LinkedList};
```

and index.ts:

```
import {LinkedList} from "./linked_list";
class LinkedListStack{
  *****
}
```

My compiler compiles them into:

linked_list.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.LinkedList = void 0;

var Node = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Node(value) {
        *****
    }
}());
var LinkedList = /** @class */ (function () {
    function LinkedList() {
        *****
}());
exports.LinkedList = LinkedList;
//# sourceMappingURL=linked_list.js.map
```

and index.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var linked_list_1 = require("./linked_list");
var LinkedListStack = /** @class */ (function () {
    function LinkedListStack() {
        *****
}());

//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

and i get this error in my browser when i refer my  to index.js:

*index.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at index.ts:1:1*

I have tried to change my tsconfig.json file to "module": "commonjs" but it doesn't work.

If i try to change my "require" and "exports" in js files to "import" and "export" i get this error in the browser:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*

These are my:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
***
<body>

  <script>const exports = {};</script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "js",
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Comment: Because `"module": "commonjs",` in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: you mean i must delete it or what. Please explain further!)

Comment: Your question is: _"Why does my compiler compiles import in index.ts file into require with specifications to index.js file?"_ The answer is: _"Because `"module": "commonjs",` in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`."_ If that's not enough, read the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Comment: oh, i understood u fully, but didn't I mention that i want to solve this problem lmao?

Comment: What problem? What is the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

CommonJS is usually used for node.js projects, not in the browser. You probably want `"module": "es2015"` in your tsconfig.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Comment: if I do create a new file extends_linked_list.js, import my linked_list.js and print a new instance of it's class console.log doesn't log anything whereas in linked_list.js itself everything prints just fine.

Comment: Please either write a complete answer or add a comment. This doesn't really answer the complete question.